# Spring-data-neo4j NullPointerException when get children

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am currently working on spring-data-neo4j and need to get the children of certain nodes.

Here is the domain

```
@NodeEntity
public class GLNode {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property(name="description")
    private ArrayList<String> desc;

    public ArrayList<String> getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "GLRelationship")
    private Collection<GLNode> children;

    public Collection<GLNode> getChildren(){
        return this.children;
    }

}
```

here is the repository

```
@Query("MATCH (n:GLNode) WHERE id(n)={0} RETURN n")
GLNode getGLNodeFromId(Integer idOfNode);
```

In the service, I successfully get the node but get null pointer when try to access its children like:

```
    GLNode m = repo.getGLNodeFromId(0);
    System.out.println(m.getChildren().iterator().next().getDesc().toString());
```

Here's the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.services.GLService.getGLNodes(GLService.java:40)
    com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.controllers.GLController.getGLNodes(GLController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:24)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

I am sure `m` has been successfully retrieved. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that `desc` never gets initialised and the NPE gets thrown right before `.iterator()`

Answer (score 1):

`getChildren()` will be null with your custom query

```
@Query("MATCH (n:GLNode) WHERE id(n)={0} RETURN n")
GLNode getGLNodeFromId(Integer idOfNode);
```

because the query returns only the node and no relationships (depth 0).

If you are retrieving the node by ID, then `repository.findOne(id)` or `neo4jOperations.load(GLNode.class,id)` would be more appropriate. These methods load entities to a default depth of 1 which means, related entities one hop away.

You can change this default depth using `repository.findOne(id,depth)` or `neo4jOperations.load(GLNode.class,id,depth)`